# Use bool expression in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML

```
<div ng-image="Content/Images/Items/{{item.Name}}.png" ng-flag="item.Name == true">
```

JS

```
application.directive('ngImage', function() {
return {
    scope: {
        ngFlag: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var use = attrs.ngFlag;

        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.ngImage + ')',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        });
    }
}
})
```

var "use" is "item.Name == true", but i wanted get false/true. How do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s better to use ng-style instead of custom directive

Controller:

```
$scope.getStyles = function(item) {
    if (item.Name){
        return {
            'background-image': 'url(Content/Images/Items/' + item.Name +'.png)',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-style="getStyles(item)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the interpolation operator {{}} as you did in the other attribute.

```
ng-flag="{{item.Name == true}}"
```